# create-react-app is not working and it's taking forever, any suggestions?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I've just finished up a React course and wanted to get practicing. However, I can't seem to get a project going using create-react-app.

When I use **create-react-app projectname** in the commandline, it starts installing, but it takes half an hour before it finally gives up and shows me a bunch of errors I can't seem to wrap my head around. When I watch tutorials on how to use create-react-app, it seems like it should work fine and should be finished in about 12 seconds.

I've already tried numerous things:

- Checked whether npm, node and npx are installed
- Running CMDer (the CLI I use) as an administrator
- npm install -g create-react-app followed by create-react-app projectname
- npm install -g create-react-app followed by npm create-react-app projectname
- npm init react-app projectname
- Uninstalling create-react-app and installing again
- npx create-react app projectname
- Disabling my firewall and anti-virus and doing all of the above
- Cleared the npm cache
- Updated npm to the latest version

**This is the last part of my log, above all this are just a bunch of silly SaveTree lines.**

```
28892 silly saveTree `-- react@16.8.6
28893 warn ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
28894 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\eslint-module-utils' -> 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE'
28895 verbose cwd C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest
28896 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
28897 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts"
28898 verbose node v10.15.3
28899 verbose npm  v6.4.1
28900 error path C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\eslint-module-utils
28901 error code EPERM
28902 error errno -4048
28903 error syscall rename
28904 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\eslint-module-utils' -> 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE'
28904 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\eslint-module-utils' -> 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE']
28904 error   cause:
28904 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\eslint-module-utils' -> 'C:\Users\Dave\MyProjects\Portfolio\Tickomatic\newest\node_modules\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE'
28904 error      errno: -4048,
28904 error      code: 'EPERM',
28904 error      syscall: 'rename',
28904 error      path:
28904 error       'C:\\Users\\Dave\\MyProjects\\Portfolio\\Tickomatic\\newest\\node_modules\\eslint-module-utils',
28904 error      dest:
28904 error       'C:\\Users\\Dave\\MyProjects\\Portfolio\\Tickomatic\\newest\\node_modules\\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE' },
28904 error   stack:
28904 error    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename \'C:\\Users\\Dave\\MyProjects\\Portfolio\\Tickomatic\\newest\\node_modules\\eslint-module-utils\' -> \'C:\\Users\\Dave\\MyProjects\\Portfolio\\Tickomatic\\newest\\node_modules\\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE\'',
28904 error   errno: -4048,
28904 error   code: 'EPERM',
28904 error   syscall: 'rename',
28904 error   path:
28904 error    'C:\\Users\\Dave\\MyProjects\\Portfolio\\Tickomatic\\newest\\node_modules\\eslint-module-utils',
28904 error   dest:
28904 error    'C:\\Users\\Dave\\MyProjects\\Portfolio\\Tickomatic\\newest\\node_modules\\.eslint-module-utils.DELETE',
28904 error   parent: 'newest' }
28905 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
28905 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
28905 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
28905 error
28905 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
28905 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
28905 error the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
28906 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

As far as I can tell it has something to do with it not being able to rename a certain file and my operation system (Windows in my case) rejecting the entire thing because of this. I'm not sure if that's correct but that's all I can figure out and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any suggestions? I can't seem to find a solution for this and I'm not familiar with WebPack so I can't set the project up manually at this moment in time.

Thanks a bunch in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dropbox or something similar that is syncing the directory, that might be causing this problem.

also try to update the npm using:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: I've updated to the latest version using your command, I'm at 6.9.0 now but the commands still don't work. I've tried clearing the cache as well but that didn't work either. I'm not using dropbox or anything similar btw.

Comment: Hey! This works fully for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the *create-react-app* globally by:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

and it solved my issue. However, I'm using 6.9.0 version for npm and 12.5.0 for node.